# Excel IF and OR formula

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

[My attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cxQ9.jpg**)

I'm trying to use the IF statement so that when excel is looking at row A and row B, it'll give the result in Row C.

If the formula scan row A and B, and both A and B is NA, then row C come up to NA.

If A come up as NA, and B come up as Denied, then row C will show up as Denied.

If A come up as reimbursed and B come up as NA, then C will show up as reimbursed.

here's my formula:

> =IF(AND(A2 = "NA", B2 = "NA"),"NA",IF(OR(A2="Denied",B2 ="Denied"),"Denied","NA"))

Can I get some tip on how to include "reimbursed" in the formula?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=IF(OR(A2="Denied", B2="Denied"), 
    "Denied", 
    IF(OR(A2="Reimbursed", B2="Reimbursed"), 
        "Reimbursed", 
        "NA"
    )
)
```